# My app crashed and I didn't get any response from server. But I got a response using postman

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am sending the PatientInfo() class object to the server but I didn't get any response from the server. The "response.body()" is getting null. But I am getting the JSON format in my logcat .

**My patientInfo() model class---**

```
public class PatientInfo implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("patient_id")
@Expose
private String patientId;
@SerializedName("firstname")
@Expose
private String firstname;
@SerializedName("lastname")
@Expose
private String lastname;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("mobile")
@Expose
private String mobile;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("sex")
@Expose
private String sex;
@SerializedName("blood_group")
@Expose
private String bloodGroup;
@SerializedName("date_of_birth")
@Expose
private String dateOfBirth;
@SerializedName("affliate")
@Expose
private Object affliate;
@SerializedName("picture")
@Expose
private String picture;
@SerializedName("created_by")
@Expose
private String createdBy;
@SerializedName("create_date")
@Expose
private String createDate;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("user_role")
@Expose
private String userRole;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPatientId() {
    return patientId;
}

public void setPatientId(String patientId) {
    this.patientId = patientId;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public String getBloodGroup() {
    return bloodGroup;
}

public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
}

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public Object getAffliate() {
    return affliate;
}

public void setAffliate(Object affliate) {
    this.affliate = affliate;
}

public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public String getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PatientInfo{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", patientId='" + patientId + '\'' +
            ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
            ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
            ", mobile='" + mobile + '\'' +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", sex='" + sex + '\'' +
            ", bloodGroup='" + bloodGroup + '\'' +
            ", dateOfBirth='" + dateOfBirth + '\'' +
            ", affliate=" + affliate +
            ", picture='" + picture + '\'' +
            ", createdBy='" + createdBy + '\'' +
            ", createDate='" + createDate + '\'' +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", userRole='" + userRole + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

**My RegResponse() class--**

```
public class RegResponse implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("user_data")
@Expose
private List<PatientInfo> patientInfoList;

public List<PatientInfo> getPatientInfoList() {
    return patientInfoList;
}

public void setPatientInfoList(List<PatientInfo> patientInfoList) {
    this.patientInfoList = patientInfoList;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RegResponse{" +
            "status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", message='" + message + '\'' +
            ", patientInfoList=" + patientInfoList +
            '}';
}
```

}

**My RegSuccessResponse() class----**

```
public class RegSuccessResponse implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private RegResponse response;

public RegResponse getResponse() {
    return response;
}
public void setResponse(RegResponse response) {
    this.response = response;

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RegSuccessResponse{" +
            "response=" + response +
            '}';
}
```

}

**here is my Api interface ---**

```
public interface HMSAPIService {@POST("auth/registration")
Call<RegSuccessResponse> doReg(@Body PatientInfo patientInfo);}
```

**and finaly here is my RegistrationActivity() code--**

```
       String firstName = metFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
       String lastName = metLastName.getText().toString().trim();
       String email = metregEmail.getText().toString().trim();
       String password = metRegPassword.getText().toString().trim();
       String phoneNumber = metPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
       String mobileNumber = metMobileNumber.getText().toString().trim();
       String bloodGroup = spBloodGroup.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
       String gender = spGender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
       String dob = metDob.getText().toString().trim();
       String path = tvPicName.getText().toString().trim();
       String address = metAddress.getText().toString().trim();




       patientInfo.setFirstname(firstName);
       patientInfo.setLastname(lastName);
       patientInfo.setEmail(email);
       patientInfo.setPassword(password);
       patientInfo.setPhone(phoneNumber);
       patientInfo.setMobile(mobileNumber);a
       if(spBloodGroup.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-Select One-")){
           patientInfo.setBloodGroup(null);
       } else {
           patientInfo.setBloodGroup(bloodGroup);
       }
       if(spGender.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-Select One-")){
           patientInfo.setSex(null);
       } else {
           patientInfo.setSex(gender);
       }
       patientInfo.setDateOfBirth(dob);
       patientInfo.setPicture(path);
       patientInfo.setAddress(address);

       if (regSuccessResponse.getResponse() != null) {
           if (regSuccessResponse.getResponse().getPatientInfoList() != null) {
               regSuccessResponse.getResponse().getPatientInfoList().add(patientInfo);
           }
       }

       Gson gson = new Gson();
       String patientInfoobjectstring = gson.toJson(patientInfo);
       Log.e(TAG, patientInfoobjectstring);



      Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(SharedPref.BASE_URL)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();

       hmsapiService =  retrofit.create(HMSAPIService.class);



       Call<RegSuccessResponse> call = hmsapiService.doReg(patientInfo);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<RegSuccessResponse>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<RegSuccessResponse> call, Response<RegSuccessResponse> response) {

               regSuccessResponse = response.body();
               if (response.body() != null){

                   if (response.body().getResponse().getStatus().equals("ok")) {
                       Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration successful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class).putExtra("go_to", "patient_info"));
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                       Log.d(TAG, regSuccessResponse.getResponse().getMessage());
                       finish();
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Status not found.......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
           }
           else
               {
                   Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Check your connection!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<RegSuccessResponse> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");

           }
       });


   }

   else {

       Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.reg_linear_layout), R.string.all_data_providing_message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

   });
```

//my server response will be like

```
{"status":"error","message":"There have no data!"}
```

**my logcat shows---**

```
2018-11-29 17:53:30.329 23861-23861/com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms E/RegistrationActivity:{"address":"Dhaka","blood_group":"O+","date_of_birth":"29/11/2018","email":"shaon054@gmail.com","firstname":"Shaon","lastname":"acharjee","mobile":"494518","password":"sgshsuvs","phone":"4728151","picture":"/storage/emulated/0/demonuts/1543492405451.jpg","sex":"Male"}2018-11-29 17:53:39.194 23861-23861/com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms, PID: 23861
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms.models.RegResponse com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms.responses.RegSuccessResponse.getResponse()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms.activities.RegistrationActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(RegistrationActivity.java:259)
    at com.example.bdtask.bdtaskhms.activities.-$$Lambda$RegistrationActivity$CvYkDzuJ5whfAnUqX8zPIFxXXqo.onClick(lambda)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11159)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you are trying to use `regSuccessResponse` before you initialize it.

Comment: @Vladyslav, I have initialized it inside my RegistrationActivity().As I gave a part o my RegistrationActivity, it is missed. kindly tell me how can i fix this.TIA

Comment: which line? Show the line

Comment: regSuccessResponse = new RegSuccessResponse();

Comment: there is no such line in your code.

Comment: try using the response.body() only once . You're calling it twice , first in                regSuccessResponse = response.body(); and then in the null check

Comment: @Vladyslav  , I have put here only a part of RegistrationActivity. That's why this line is not there. bt i initialized it inside the OnCreate().

Comment: Looks like I you did it incorrectly.

Comment: @Vladyslav   , where brother?

Comment: don't know, you didn't show it.

Comment: @Vladyslav May I get your Email address?

Comment: that's not how StackOverflow works, sorry. Please add the code where you initialize it

Comment: @Vladyslav    brother here I initialize the regSuccessResponse.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
      progressDialog = new SpotsDialog(RegistrationActivity.this, R.style.Custom);
        patientInfo = new PatientInfo();
        regResponse = new RegResponse();
        regSuccessResponse = new RegSuccessResponse();